# Посчитать гомографию (ошибка в цикле for в Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

Пытаюсь решить мотодом наименьших квадратов систему двух матриц `Ab=0`.

```
pts2d = np.array([[1.0486, -0.3645], [-1.6851, -0.4004], [-0.9437, -0.42], [1.0682, 0.0699], [0.6077, -0.0771], [1.2543, -0.6454], [-0.2709, 0.8635], [-0.4571, -0.3645], [-0.7902, 0.0307], [0.7318, 0.6382], [-1.058, 0.3312], [0.3464, 0.3377], [0.3137, 0.1189], [-0.431, 0.0242], [-0.4799, 0.292], [0.6109, 0.083], [-0.4081, 0.292], [-0.1109, -0.2992], [0.5129, -0.0575], [0.1406, -0.4527]])
 pts3d = np.array([[1.5706, -0.149, 0.2598], [-1.5282, 0.9695, 0.3802], [-0.6821, 1.2856, 0.4078], [0.4124, -1.0201, -0.0915], [1.2095, 0.2812, -0.128], [0.8819, -0.8481, 0.5255], [-0.9442, -1.1583, -0.3759], [0.0415, 1.3445, 0.324], [-0.7975, 0.3017, -0.0826], [-0.4329, -1.4151, -0.2774], [-1.1475, -0.0772, -0.2667], [-0.5149, -1.1784, -0.1401], [0.1993, -0.2854, -0.2114], [-0.432, 0.2143, -0.1053], [-0.7481, -0.384, -0.2408], [0.8078, -0.1196, -0.2631], [-0.7605, -0.5792, -0.1936], [0.3237, 0.797, 0.217], [1.3089, 0.5786, -0.1887], [1.2323, 1.4421, 0.4506]])
u = pts2d[:,0]
v = pts2d[:,1]
X = pts3d[:,0]
Y = pts3d[:,1]
Z = pts3d[:,2]
A = np.zeros(40,12)
  for i in range[1:2:40]:
     for j in range ((i + 1) / 2):
     A([i:i + 1], [:]) = mcat([X(j), Y(j), Z(j) [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] - u(j)*X(j)-u(j)*Y(j)-u(j)*Z(j)-u(j), [0, 0, 0, 0] X(j), Y(j), Z(j), [1] - v(j)*X(j)-v(j)*Y(j)-v(j)*Z(j)-v(j)])
```

Получаю

> for i in range[1:2:40]:
>       ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent

Ошибка в определении цикла for?
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: У вас два вопроса с одинаковыми ошибками, не ленитесь, прочитайте учебник по python, разберитесь с синтаксисом и большинство вопросов отпадут сами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `python` очень важны отступы, так как отступами определяются вложенные блоки.
Соответственно отступы должны быть всегда однотипными и состоять из 4 пробелов (согласно [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)).

У вас сейчас в коде много ошибок:

1. Неверно расставлены отступы, об этом вам говорит ошибка `IndentationError`. Во второй строке и в циклах.
2. Неверное обращение к массиву `A([i:i + 1], [:])`, круглые скобки лишние, должно быть так `A[i:i+1, :]`
3. Неверное обращения к массивам `X(j), Y(j), Z(j)`, в `python` индексы указываются в квадратных скобках
4. В первом цикле неверный вызов функции `range`. Должны быть круглые скобки, а вы обращаетесь к `range` как к итерируемому объекту и пытаетесь взять от него срез.

Answer (score 0):

```
pts2d = np.array([[1.0486, -0.3645], [-1.6851, -0.4004], [-0.9437, -0.42], [1.0682, 0.0699], [0.6077, -0.0771], [1.2543, -0.6454], [-0.2709, 0.8635], [-0.4571, -0.3645], [-0.7902, 0.0307], [0.7318, 0.6382], [-1.058, 0.3312], [0.3464, 0.3377], [0.3137, 0.1189], [-0.431, 0.0242], [-0.4799, 0.292], [0.6109, 0.083], [-0.4081, 0.292], [-0.1109, -0.2992], [0.5129, -0.0575], [0.1406, -0.4527]])
pts3d = np.array([[1.5706, -0.149, 0.2598], [-1.5282, 0.9695, 0.3802], [-0.6821, 1.2856, 0.4078], [0.4124, -1.0201, -0.0915], [1.2095, 0.2812, -0.128], [0.8819, -0.8481, 0.5255], [-0.9442, -1.1583, -0.3759], [0.0415, 1.3445, 0.324], [-0.7975, 0.3017, -0.0826], [-0.4329, -1.4151, -0.2774], [-1.1475, -0.0772, -0.2667], [-0.5149, -1.1784, -0.1401], [0.1993, -0.2854, -0.2114], [-0.432, 0.2143, -0.1053], [-0.7481, -0.384, -0.2408], [0.8078, -0.1196, -0.2631], [-0.7605, -0.5792, -0.1936], [0.3237, 0.797, 0.217], [1.3089, 0.5786, -0.1887], [1.2323, 1.4421, 0.4506]])
 u = pts2d[:,0]
 v = pts2d[:,1]
 X = pts3d[:,0]
 Y = pts3d[:,1]
 Z = pts3d[:,2]
 A = np.zeros(40,12)
for i in range(1,2,40):
 for j in range ((i + 1) / 2): 
     A[i:i+1, :] = np.concatenate(X[j], Y[j], Z[j]  1, 0, 0, 0, 0 - u[j]*X[j]-u[j]*Y[j]-u[j]*Z[j]-u[j] 0, 0, 0, 0 X[j], Y[j], Z[j], 1 - v[j]*X[j]-v[j]*Y[j]-v[j]*Z[j]-v[j])
U, D, V = np.linalg.svd(A)
```

Comment: У вас с отступами и здесь беда. `u,v,X,Y,Z,A` сдвинуты на один пробел.  Внутренний `for` должен быть сдвинуть на 4 пробела.